# apk expansion files in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk-expansion-files

i got a 231MB apk and I just want to upload it to google play. I know that google play accepts 50MB apps and mine has broken the 50MB limit.I know I should use apk expansion files for it. But I don't know where to start. I am using now android studio as my IDE for android development. any tutorials would help

Comment: Good tutorial available here : http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.in/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html
Google Developer site : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en